# What is the fastest way to get a single XML element in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, indexing

I want an indexed (fast and efficient) way for PHP to skip to, and get, a single XML-element. Just like how, in SQL, you'd use a `WHERE` statement to get a single row from an indexed column.

SimpleXML parser *downloads* the entire XML file, while XMLReader *traverses* the entire file, just to get to that single desired element. Those take a lot of time...

So what's the quickest hack (or parser-program) to skip *directly* to the 37th `<item>` *WITHOUT* going through items 1-36?

### My Preference

If I have to use the optional `num="37"` attribute below, as an artificial index, then I will, but I'd rather just delete it, and instead have the program magically figure out which `<item>` is 37th.

Here's my code:

### XML

```xml
<answers>
    <item num="1"> Lorem </item>
    <item num="2"> ipsum </item>
    <item num="3"> dolor </item>
    .
    .
    .
    etc.
</answers>
```

### PHP

```
$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open("file.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

while($xml->read()) {
    if ($xml->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $xml->localName == "item") {
            $xml->read();
            echo $xml->value;
    };
};
return;
```

Comment: Then look at using [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

Comment: I had the impression that XPath only works on SimpleXML parser.   Can it be made to work with XMLReader?

Comment: No, xpath works with SimpleXML; if you have the memory to load your file, then it's the fastest way to access the nth element

Comment: Sure, my file is fairly small (300 `<item>`s, & 1000 lines, when you could their children).    But is SimpleXML really fastest?  Because, you see, my 100 users or so are going to be triggering one of these XML-queries every 3 seconds.  It seems unreasonable to be re-downloading the whole XML file, every single time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to parse XML documents in an efficient manner.

### DomCrawler

Symfony's [DomCrawler](https://github.com/symfony/dom-crawler) component has the API to parse HTML/XML documents with both XPath and CSS. Have a look:

```php
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$xml = <<<XML
<root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
    <answers>
        <item num="1">dolor1</item>
        <item num="2">dolor2</item>
        <item num="3">dolor3</item>
        <item num="4">dolor4</item>
        <item num="5">dolor5</item>
        <item num="6">dolor6</item>
        <item num="7">dolor7</item>
        <item num="8">dolor8</item>
        <item num="9">dolor9</item>
        <item num="10">dolor10</item>
        <item num="11">dolor11</item>
        <item num="12">dolor12</item>
        <item num="13">dolor13</item>
        <item num="14">dolor14</item>
    </answers>
</root>
XML;

$crawler = new Crawler($xml);

$target = $crawler->filterXPath('//root/answers/item[@num="13"]');

var_dump($target->text());
// Outputs: dolor13
```

### Installation

As you may already know, before utilizing that `Crawler` class, you need to install the package through [Composer](http://getcomposer.org) and include the autoloader in your code.

```
composer require symfony/dom-crawler
```

Or if you don't want to use Composer, [as you stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41434307/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-a-single-xml-element-in-php/41434594#comment70075980_41434594), you can install it manually using Git (or you can [download a zipball](https://github.com/symfony/dom-crawler/releases) instead):

```bsh
cd my/project
mkdir -p vendor/symfony
git clone https://github.com/symfony/dom-crawler vendor/symfony/dom-crawler
```

Either way, you still need a [PSR-4 autoloader](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) (which composer provides out of the box). Quoting from the DomCrawler docs:

> *Use the official Git repository (https://github.com/symfony/dom-crawler).
>   Then, require the vendor/autoload.php file to enable the autoloading mechanism provided by Composer [or any other PSR-4 autoloader]. Otherwise, your application won't be able to find the classes of this Symfony component.*

So, have a look at [Example Implementations of PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/) and create an autoloader for your project. You might want to look into [Symfony's `ClassLoader`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader.html) component or [`phpab`](https://github.com/theseer/Autoload) which can generate namespace-aware autoloaders for your project.

But I strongly recommend you to look into Composer. It's not what you think it is. It will change your daily life as a developer.

### Performance

It's a really tiny XML document to parse, so these benchmarks are not really reliable, but anyways:

```bsh
$ time php xmlparse.php
string(7) "dolor13"
php xmlparse.php  0.06s user 0.09s system 55% cpu 0.278 total

$ time php xmlparse.php
string(7) "dolor13"
php xmlparse.php  0.06s user 0.08s system 60% cpu 0.239 total

$ time php xmlparse.php
string(7) "dolor13"
php xmlparse.php  0.06s user 0.08s system 55% cpu 0.257 total
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  BTW, that composer link is misspelled.  (I can't fix it myself, because all edits by other posters, have to be at least 6 characters long.).

Comment: Ah, fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Dear Sephehr:  Thanks for the suggestion, and for all your edits of my OP, but I'm scared to download something as massive as Composer, which supposedly manages things for me, and could therefore take over my system, without my knowing it.  Is there an easier way to get the Crawler class?

Comment: You're welcome @rudminda. Yes, you can install the DomCrawler component without composer. I updated my answer to reflect on that. And... composer is massive in a sense that it took the PHP world and pushed it forward. It's not the beast you see. Even modern frameworks like Laravel are built around Composer and its packages. I highly recommend you to look into Composer and change your perspective. It will change your life as a developer.